# is it possible to save files in cache directory from phonegap?

Tags: cordova, caching, directory

Is it possible to save files in cache directory from phonegap?

thanks

zipi

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Juste replace cordova.file.dataDirectory with cordova.file.cacheDirectory (I think that's the right name)

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
    cordova.file.dataDirectory, 
    function gotDir(dir) {
        console.log("Data directory located");
        dir.getFile(sessionID + ".html", {create:true},
                    function(file) {
                        console.log("got the file", file);
                        file.createWriter(this.gotFileWriter,
                                          function fail() {
                                              console.log("Unable to create the writer");
                                         });
                });
    }
    function fail() 
        console.log("Unable to locate the cache");
});
```